# Consuming API of certain endpoints using Vue Components within Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, api-design

I have been browsing for a while to find a viable solution.

I have a **Laravel** application where I have certain endpoints in **API** route.

I would like to consume the data without needing to log into application itself. I would appreciate if some body can guide me in the right direction. I have looked into **Passport**, however I wouldn't like to pass certain information like `client_id` or `client_secret` in **ajax** calls as they can easily be **seen**.

Comment: If you don't want to log into the application to get access, then make your endpoints public. Else, you will have to somehow get access tokens if your routes are protected

Comment: @EddyTheDove, that's what I am trying to understand. I do want the end points to be protected.. However at the same time, I should be able to call it. Just trying to understand what would be the right way to go on about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents approach to the problem I was facing. might help some one in the future.

After quite a bit of research and understanding how JWT works which by the way I still need to research a bit more to fully understand it. However, to get an overview I can't find a better article to explain in simple words other than https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token.

Now, once I understood how JWT works, it was easy for me to wrap my head around the whole flow. So here is how I approached it. As I am working on an internal API for my company, I created a middleware to check whether a request to certain endpoints is coming from whitelisted API which you can easily get from $request->api().

Then I installed the excellent package by tymondesigns at https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth. I followed the installation and generated the secret key. Now here comes the fun part.

I wanted the end points to be secured without needing for me to be logged in, hence I created my own middleware where I grabbed certain user from my users table and created a JWT token from that user object.

$user = App\User::whereEmail('email')->first()
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

once I got the token all I needed to do was to call my end point i.e. /api/v1/users?token={generatedToken} and voila !!! all good to go. However, we also need to refresh the token after certain time, which again the package thankfully provide two middlewares

jwt.auth and jwt.refresh

jwt.auth midleware tries to create token using authenticate method through credentials, so i swapped it for my middleware where I authenticate user as above and jwt.refreshes the token.

If you read the article I mentioned and then read the package wiki it will all make sense. Cheerio !!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have both. You cannot protect a route, then call it without authenticating. Then there is no point protecting it in the first place if you can access unauthenticated. Make your life easier, define the same route twice. Once in the middleware, once out of the middleware.

```
Route::get('link', 'LinkController@get');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::get('link', 'LinkController@get');
});
```

Now you have both, protected and unprotected routes. But, as I said, not it's literally unprotected because anyone can access it without authenticating.

Comment: I am aware of making the endpoint public and then getting the data from there. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. What I want to achieve is some way of me being able to hit the end point securely while if the end user browse to that end point then it redirects him/her back to specified page. So, would it be possible to call endpoint from my component with unique token or information, where my end point then checks if that request is internal and spit out required data.

Comment: I think so. Just copy your token from the database and manually add it to your request headers. That's it.